# Javascript alerts showing multiple times

Tags: javascript, alerts

I am only a new programmer so this is probably a simple fix, this is the code I have, however it is producing multiple alert windows with the same message in some circumstances. Can anyone help me with this? Sorry if the coding is a bit clumsy!

```
<script>
 
document.addEventListener('BeforeFormSubmit', function(event) {

 if (event.detail.appKey == 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx') {

     let checkValue1 = document.querySelector("input[id*='InsertRecordno_of_selections_qty1']").value;
    
     if (checkValue1 > '1') {
     event.preventDefault();
     alert("There too many lines selected for Qty 1");
     return false;
    }
}

  if (event.detail.appKey == 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx') {

     let checkValue2 = document.querySelector("input[id*='InsertRecordno_of_selections_qty2']").value;
    
     if (checkValue2 > '1') {
     event.preventDefault();
     alert("There too many lines selected for Qty 2");
     return false;
    }
}

 if (event.detail.appKey == 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx') {

     let checkValue3 = document.querySelector("input[id*='InsertRecordno_of_selections_qty3']").value;
    
     if (checkValue3 > '1') {
     event.preventDefault();
     alert("There too many lines selected for Qty 3");
     return false;
    }
}

 if (event.detail.appKey == 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx') {

     let checkValue4 = document.querySelector("input[id*='InsertRecordno_of_selections_qty4']").value;
    
     if (checkValue4 > '1') {
     event.preventDefault();
     alert("There too many lines selected for Qty 4");
     return false;
    }
}

 if (event.detail.appKey == 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx') {

     let checkValue5 = document.querySelector("input[id*='InsertRecordno_of_selections_qty5']").value;
    
     if (checkValue5 > '1') {
     event.preventDefault();
     alert("There too many lines selected for Qty 5");
     return false;
    }
}
  });
</script>
```

Much appreciated

Comment: Do you somehow bind this `BeforeFormSubmit` event in loop/in another event? Can you provide minimal example of your issue?

Comment: Hello,  could you provide all the code please (html part) ? You could probably factorize your code.

Comment: @m50 I can't easily access the html coding as this javascript is what I've added on to a submit button on our Caspio platform (Caspio is a low coding app builder)

Comment: @Justinas certainly not knowingly, this is the only code on that button if that helps?

Comment: BeforeFormSubmit  event is called multiple times. There is no issue is above written code. I hope so.

Comment: BeforeFormSubmit event is called multiple times. There is no issue is above written code. I hope so.
Needs to see the complete code to diagnose properly.

Comment: Without more context I can't say for sure, but my bet is on [event bubnling](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_bubbling)
It happens when you have nested elements event gets called multiple time going from parent to parent, so if you have something like that that could be the issue